# Can I type string values in sql queries without ' symbols around value?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am creating query constructor for myself to make future coding easier and at this moment I have this code in my method:

```
public static String constructQueryValueRemove(String table, Pair pairIndex, String column){
    String query;
    if (pairIndex.getRight() instanceof Number){
        query = "UPDATE `"+table+
                "` SET `"+column+"` = NULL" +
                "WHERE `"+table+"`.`"+pairIndex.getLeft()+"` = "+pairIndex.getRight();
    } else {
        query = "UPDATE `"+table+
                "` SET `"+column+"` = NULL" +
                "WHERE `"+table+"`.`"+pairIndex.getLeft()+"` = '"+pairIndex.getRight().toString()+"'";
    }
    return query;
}
```

Will this query below work correctly if pairIndex.getRight() will be string and value will be without ' symbols around?

```
query = "UPDATE `"+table+"`"+
        "SET `"+column+"` = NULL" +
        "WHERE `"+table+"`.`"+pairIndex.getLeft()+"` = "+pairIndex.getRight();
```

Comment: Use prepared queries. Also why don't you try it yourself? Asking us to build up a testing environment is way more complicated and time consuming than just executing a query and *observe*

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that would not be a valid SQL command, since the string is unquoted. It would be simpler to create a prepared statement, then bind the dynamic values (such as the given string). The prepared statement will handle the proper quoting internally.

See here for details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

By the way, take a look at [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/), [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/), and [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/), for some frameworks that make it easy to build SQL queries in java.

Comment: Thank you. I am taking look at Querydsl. It looks really good.